# Grafana Loki LogQL : filter legends value

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I do not understand how to logql grouping legend under histogram explore, how to display log level using logql ?

[image: grafana loki explore view]

Comment: how's the logs look like?

Answer (score 0):

That is the default legend when no other grouping option is selected.